# numpy version from pip list and from print __version__ are different

Tags: numpy, google-colaboratory

Seeing the following error on colab "RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0x10 but this version of numpy is 0xf" at line

```
from skimage import exposure
```

I can see that there is a mismatch in version and numpy needs to be upgraded. But latest version is already installed. When I try to uninstall and install or do upgrade it is installing the latest version of 1.24.3 but whenever I print it still says 1.22.4.

```
!python -m pip list | grep numpy
import numpy as np2
print(np2.__version__)

numpy                         1.24.3
1.22.4


!python -m pip uninstall numpy --y
!python -m pip install numpy --upgrade
import numpy
print(numpy.__version__)

Found existing installation: numpy 1.24.3
Uninstalling numpy-1.24.3:
  Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.24.3
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.24.3-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (17.3 MB)
Installing collected packages: numpy
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
tensorflow 2.12.0 requires numpy<1.24,>=1.22, but you have numpy 1.24.3 which is incompatible.
numba 0.56.4 requires numpy<1.24,>=1.18, but you have numpy 1.24.3 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed numpy-1.24.3

1.22.4
```

Tried printing numpy file and deleting numpy folder from that location, hoping 1.22.4 version would go away. But that did nothing

```
print(np2.__file__)
```

Are there multiple versions ? How do I find where 1.22.4 is installed so that I can remove it. pip uninstall numpy does not work. It is uninstalling the 1.24.3 version but not the 1.22.4 version

Comment: Restart the Kernel when you install new versions of packages that you had already imported, assuming by your code that you are using a Notebook